# String or binary data would be truncated - when inserting to #temp table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, temp-tables

My `#temp` table column is defined as `VARCHAR(10)`, input eg: value is 'Azure'. The data is coming from a table where the column is defined as `VARCHAR(100)`, but the `TOP 1` query that inserts into the temp table is bringing back only values as big as 6 but I am still getting a error:

> String or binary data would be truncated

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I'd a question while I was on it, but got the answer and posted the same below. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Even though the specific values being inserted is of max size 6, if there are bigger values in the source table, say eg: 'Slightly bigger text' (which is 20), the `#temp` insert fails if it is a TOP query.

Safe bet, size your temp table columns as per the original size of the base data column definition, and you wouldn't waste time like me :) There are so many bigger `VARCHAR` columns in the `#temp` table being inserted along with, and one wouldn't think that a `VARCHAR(10)` vs `VARCHAR(20)` would make a difference for a value with `LEN()=5`.